# Return an Array of Indexes for Matching Values in a Primary Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array with multiple duplicates.  I'm trying to write code that will produce a second array that contains the indexes of all of the elements in the first array that equal a look up value.

For example, I have this array:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
7
```

I want a second array that will return the indexes of the number 6.

This is the code that I have right now.

```
Sub test()
Dim look_up As Integer
Dim id_ar As Variant
Dim index_ar As Variant


look_up = 6
id_ar = Range("A1:A16").Value
index_ar = Application.Match(id_ar, look_up, True)

End Sub
```

I want this to result in an array like this:

```
13
14
```

But it just returns a bunch of '#N/A's

Comment: Without having tried anything, I notice something. Dim look_up As Integer followed by an integer named lookup instead of look_up

Comment: @Uvar whoops, somehow I must have changed that when I copied it over.  The variable names match up in the code I'm running.  I edited the question to fix that.  Thank you.

Comment: Not to keep beating the same problem, but your Application.Match also mentions `lookup` instead of `look_up`. Is that correct in the code as well?

Comment: @Busse yes, that is correct in my code. Thanks for seeing that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extremely simple code may help you better than brief and concise approaches.

Definitions : arrOut is your desired output, rngLookup is where your number 6 and any others reside. rngDB is where you want to search for the indexes of the lookup values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dupes()
Dim rngLookup, rngDB As Range
Dim i, j As Variant
Dim arrOut As New Collection

Set rngLookup = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
Set rngDB = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A14")


Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

For Each i In rngLookup

    For Each j In rngDB
        counter = counter + 1
        If j.Value = i.Value Then
            arrOut.Add Item:=CInt(counter)
        Else
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If you need an array output. Use this code from Brett's page.[link](https://brettdotnet.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/convert-a-collection-to-an-array-vba/)

Comment: I'm a little worried about using a loop because I want the code to be able to perform quickly with scale.  I'm not sure how long it would take if the collection had 100,000 elements.  But maybe this is the best way to solve the problem in VBA.

Comment: Hi Jarom, rest assured, the Collection data structure is a proven and reliable piece of VBA engineering. I used to be skeptical of looping till I realized that the hot path was the array at the centre of the 2 loops. Any assignment, redim and preserve at the hot path would drive an application's running time higher and higher. The collection mitigates that and can be used to scale up very quickly. If you understand how to use a collection, I'd whole heartedly recommend that one junks the array entirely.

Comment: I didn't realize this.  Thank you for clarifying.  The code you provided works perfectly.  I don't think I'll be using arrays for VBA anymore based on your rational.